# how to change the Output Directory in a LINUX makefile so that a shared object can be relatively specified in C# DLLImport?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, c#

I would like to find out how to change the Output Directory in a LINUX makefile so that a shared  object can be relatively specified in C# DLLImport?

I read the following hint in
           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316992/dll-import-path-how-to-get-dll-path-which-located-in-other-folder

Change the Output Directory setting in the C++ project to $(SolutionDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName) so that the native DLL ends up in the same folder as your managed program. Just use [DllImport("3rdparty.dll")] in your C# code. – Hans Passant Nov 29 '11 at 20:38

I would like to know to do this in a makefile used in Ubuntu Linux 15.10.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Makefile use DESTDIR to alter destination when defined andset.

Why does not:   make DESTDIR=/path install satisfy the C# DLLImport relative path requirement?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Linux 15.10 , The way I fixed this problem is to prepend "lib" to "3rdparty.so" and change  [DllImport("3rdparty.so")] in my  C# code to [DllImport("3rdparty")] .